# String to dictionary, keys are the words ended by "."

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a string containing information I need to use later in code and I want to create a dict from the string in the following way.

The string has the keys ended by " . "

I want a string like:

```
"Mem. 3000 GB Nm. Mario Andrew Ag. 34 Str. Photoliss Street Nr. 45B"
```

to become this dict:

```
{"Mem": "3000 GB", "Nm": "Mario Andrew", "Ag": "34", "Str": "Photoliss Street", "Nr": "45B"}
```

The keys can be different from a string to other so it's not following a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple and readable code using `REGEX`:

```
import re

s = "Mem. 3000 GB Nm. Mario Andrew Ag. 34 Str. Photoliss Street Nr. 45B"
# capture only words and strips the spaces
pattern = r"(\w+)\.\s*(.+?)\s*(?=\w+\.|$)"
# no need to create a list use generator
output = dict(m.groups() for m in re.finditer(pattern, s))
print(output)  # {'Mem': '3000 GB', 'Nm': 'Mario Andrew', 'Ag': '34', 'Str': 'Photoliss Street', 'Nr': '45B'}
```

Comment: a shorter solution, and you can use `ouput = dict(re.findall(pattern, s)` but this will create a `list` that you don't need it.

Answer (score 6):

Try using regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = "Mem. 3000 GB Nm. Mario Andrew Ag. 34 Str. Photoliss Street Nr. 45B"
data = re.split(r"(\w+)\.", s)[1:]

print({k: v.strip() for k, v in zip(data[::2], data[1::2])})
print(dict(zip(data[::2], data[1::2])))
```

**Output:**

```
{'Mem': '3000 GB', 'Nm': 'Mario Andrew', 'Ag': '34', 'Str': 'Photoliss Street', 'Nr': '45B'}
```

Comment: Note that your attributes value content space before and after the string  
(e.g. : ' 3000 GB ' instead of '3000 GB')

Comment: @Calvin-Ruiz. Thanks. `v.strip()` should fix that.

Answer (score 3):

Probably solution with Regex is the best, but just for the exercise, without `re`

```
foo = "Mem. 3000 GB Nm. Mario Andrew Ag. 34 Str. Photoliss Street Nr. 45B"

def parse(text):
    result = {}
    key, *mid, last_val = text.split('. ')
    for chunk in mid:
        *value, new_key = chunk.split(' ')
        result[key], key = ' '.join(value), new_key
    result[key] = last_val
    return result

print(parse(foo))
```

output:

```
{'Mem': '3000 GB', 'Nm': 'Mario Andrew', 'Ag': '34', 'Str': 'Photoliss Street', 'Nr': '45B'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
MyString = "Mem. 3000 GB Nm. Mario Andrew Ag. 34 Str. Photoliss Street Nr. 45B"
MyList = MyString.split(". ") # create list with separated arguments
i = 0
lenght = len(MyList)
temp = list()
while i < lenght:
    temp.append(MyList[i:i+2]) # separate arguments in pairs of arguments
    i+=2
MyDict = dict(temp) # convect list to dict
```

MyDict content your dict :

```
{'Mem': '3000 GB Nm', 'Mario Andrew Ag': '34 Str', 'Photoliss Street Nr': '45B'}
```

Comment: As suggested by @buran:
note that you get value and key together,e .g. '3000 GB Nm'